# How to filter legend by map content in composer with raster layers?

Tags: print-composer, legend, filter, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

Does the "Filter Legend by Map Content" button in composer of QGIs 3.2 version work only for vector layers? It seems it's a bug reported in 2.18.x version and should be fixed for 3.x versions (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/14194). However it seems that in 3.2 version the problem remains. Is there workaround to address this issue?
I've a project with several raster layers and I want to generate a map of each layer, with the specific legend items of each layer. This works very well with vector layers, including automatic maps generation through the Atlas feature. However in the case o rasters, it has no effect, and the legend items of all layers are always displayed in the composer (or layout), as you can see in the figure bellow. I tried also to set the "only show items inside current atlas feature" check box and it didn't work too.

[image: Filter Legend by Map Content button]

[image: Composer (or Layout) with the legend itens of all raster layers]